# Preserve Line Breaks - Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, domparser

When using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, is it normal that line breaks 
 tags are stripped out?

Comment: Use the built in dom parser, not simple html dom. The built in parser is an order of magnitude faster. http://whitlock.ath.cx/FastCrawl/benchmark.php

Comment: Excuse me, @ByronWhitlock, but I do not use Simple HTML DOM Parser for speed, I use it to do tons of things I simply cannot do with the DOMDocument, and it's so much easier! But, OH< what I'd do for a PHP Extension version of Simple HTML DOM Parser!

Answer (score 60):

I know this is old, but I was looking for this as well, and realized there was actually a built in option to turn off the removal of line breaks. No need to go editing the source.

The PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser's `load` function supports multiple useful parameters:

```
load($str, $lowercase=true, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
```

When calling the `load` function, simply pass `false` as the third parameter.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load("<html><head></head><body>stuff</body></html>", true, false);
```

If using `file_get_html`, it's the ninth parameter.

```
file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
```

**Edit:** For `str_get_html`, it's the fifth parameter (Thanks yitwail)

```
str_get_html($str, $lowercase=true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
```

Comment: Thank you.. Very helpful. Is it just me or are these parameters undocumented because for the life of me I could not find any official word on how to do this until I stumbled across this?

Comment: Glad I could help. I didn't find any documentation on it either. I was actually going to mod the library to add this functionality myself when I stumbled on this.

Comment: @userabuser Completely undocumented ;-/

Comment: it's the 5th parameter for `str_get_html` :)
I wonder why this isn't the default; stripping line breaks is very bad for javascript single line comments

Answer (score 21):

Was struggling with this as well, since I needed the HTML to be easily editable after processing.

Apparently there's a boolean in the `SimpleHTMLDOM` script `$stripRN`, that's set to `true` on default. It strips the `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` tags in the HTML.

Set the var to `false` (several occurences in the script..) and your problem is solved.

Comment: I **really** wish this was documented on their website.  Cheers, mate!

Comment: Check out Hiteklife answer, it appears to be a built-in (yet undocumented) functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change all `$stripRN` to false, the only one that affects this behavior is at line 816 ``:

```
// load html from string
function load($str, $lowercase=true, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT) {
```

Also consider to change line 988, because multibyte functions often are not installed on machines that do not deal with non-wester-european languages. Original line in v1.5 breaks the script immediately:

```
if (function_exists('mb_detect_encoding')) { $charset = mb_detect_encoding($this->root->plaintext . "ascii", $encoding_list = array( "UTF-8", "CP1252" ) ); } else $charset === false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were passing by here wondering if you can do the same thing in DomDocument then I'm please to say you can! - but it's a bit dirty :(

I had a snippet of code I wanted to tidy but retain the exact line breaks it contained (\n).
This is what I did....

```
// NOTE: If you're HTML isn't a full HTML document then expect DomDocument to
// start creating its own DOCTYPE, head and body tags.


// Convert \n into a pretend tag
$myContent = preg_replace("/[\n]/","<img src=\"slashN\" />",$myContent);

// Do your DOM stuff...
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($myContent);
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$myContent = $dom->saveHTML();

// Remove the \n's that DOMDocument put in itself
$myContent = preg_replace("/[\n]/","",$myContent);

// Put my own \n's back
$myContent = preg_replace("/<img src=\"slashN\" \/>/i","\n",$myContent);
```

It's important to note that I know, without a shadow of a doubt that my input contained only \n. You may want your own variations if \r\n or \t needs to be accounted for. eg slash.T or slash.RN etc

Answer (score -2):

Another option should one wish to preserve other formatting such as paragraphs & headings is to use `innertext` rather than `plaintext` then perform your own string cleaning with the result.

I realise there is a performance hit but it does allow for more granular control.