# using PHP HTML SIMPLE DOM PARSER with <pre> tag

Tags: php, html

I am using SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER PHP.

partial source of document that I want to parse is

```
<pre>

LINE 1

LINE 2

LINE 3

</pre>
```

these code is defined **$string** and

I wrote those PHP code

```
$html = str_get_html($string);

$ret = $html->find('pre',0)->plaintext;

echo $ret;
```

result is

**LINE 1 LINE 2 LINE 3**

but in web browser those HTML code is showing

**LINE 1**

**LINE 2**

**LINE 3**

---

web browser's showing is what I want.
How can I get same result in PHP?

Comment: @Skippy As per your edit, I believe the OP wanted to have the `<pre></pre>` tags displayed, as it is part of the file's content.

Comment: @Skippy No problemo. I noticed it in the question title. You're welcome :-) cheers

Comment: @Skippy Looks like he's not here. Oh well. Did you have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set Default Parameter $stripRN to false inside your `simple_html_dom.php`  file

e.g.

```
$stripRN = false;
```

change for both functions `file_get_html` & `str_get_html`

so this

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
```

becomes

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
```

and
this

```
function str_get_html($str, $lowercase=true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
```

becomes

```
function str_get_html($str, $lowercase=true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
```

- ref: http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/122/
- ref: [Preserve Line Breaks - Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812691/preserve-line-breaks-simple-html-dom-parser)

Answer (score 2):

You want to make line breaks, correct? The following should work:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($ret as $string) {
        echo "$string\n";
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work.
each line is not elements of array. <pre>~~</pre> as $ret is one variable.
Do I misunderstand?

Comment: Ah I see. I think you want to use preg_split(), or str_split(). If the substrings are six characters in length as in your example you could do this: $array = str_split($ret, 7); Now you can iterate the array, trimming it and adding line breaks.

Comment: @NeilGirardi Have a look at my answer above. The "edit" is a lot simpler than my original answer. If you can use it, great. Cheers *"Peace"*

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Reverse effect of original code.**

You can use the following to echo text on each line:

Output in browser:

LINE 1

LINE 2

LINE 3

**File content:**

```
<pre>
LINE 1

LINE 2

LINE 3
</pre>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

$lines = file('myfile.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

    echo ($line);

}

?>
```

---

**Original answer, misunderstood OP's question** yet useful code nonetheless.

You can use the following code to echo text in one line.

**File content:**

```
<pre>
LINE 1

LINE 2

LINE 3
</pre>
```

Output in browser: LINE 1 LINE 2 LINE 3

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

$lines_of_file = file("myfile.txt");
//Now $lines_of_file have an array item per each line

$file_content = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
$file_content_separated_by_spaces = explode(" ", $file_content);

echo $file_content;

?>
```

Comment: sorry, I edited question before you wrote this answer, but source code was broken, please check the question one more time.

Comment: @user2014475 Oh you want them one under the other, yes? Not next to each other?

Comment: @Skippy Glad you can make use of it. Now to do the reverse lol

Comment: @Skippy I came up with another solution and will post info about it, thanks Skippy

Comment: @user2014475 Reload this page to see my changes. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Skippy Oh well, if it will be of use for anyone, great. It was a slice, next time I'll do it twice! Oh wait, I did. So, thrice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do it with Simple HTML Dom Parser, but I was successful with Zend's Dom Query package. The following code works for maintaining the formatting of the text inside of `pre` elements:

```
$dom = new Zend\Dom\Query($html_string);
$results = $dom->execute('pre');
foreach ($results as $result) { // each $result is of type DOMElement
        echo $result->ownerDocument->saveXML($result);
}
```